# search-index with drush fails on field_collection error

Tags: search, drush

I've been rebuilding my search index using "drush search-index" for the better part of the day. There have been a few odd errors that I have handled as I went along, making some fixes in the process and learning as I went along about things I could do better. but now I am stuck as drush is exiting unexpectedly with the following error:

```
Remaining items to be indexed: 116    [ok]
WD php: Exception: Invalid field name given: field_accreditation is not a Field Collection field. in FieldCollectionItemEntity->__construct() (line 101 of /var/www/vhosts/lipid.org/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection.entity.inc).                                                                                                                 [error]
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
Indexing stalled with 116 items remaining.     [error]
The search index has been built.
```

I'm running Drupal 7.69, everything is current, with no beta or alpha stuff running

There is in fact a field with that name (field_accreditation). It's of type long text. It is not a field collection, it is not a member of any field collection and it is not referenced anywhere as a field collection (that I am able to find.

This stops my site at 96% indexed, which is generally indiscernible right now; but I expect it will become a problem shortly. Any thoughts on how to track down the source of this error?

Comment: First of all try to clear indexed data, and then re-index it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this. That was actually my starting point for this endeavor, so I began with a clean slate.